# MVVM Change Model's validation rule based on ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, polymorphism

I have a `ModelA` implements `IDataErrorInfo` with the validation rule defined inside the `ModelA`. My `ViewModelA` contains a `ListA` of type `ObservableCollection<ModelA>`, and is data bound to my `ViewA` for user interaction with the list (add, delete, edit, etc.).

Now I want a `ViewModelB` which will inherent from `ViewModelA`, and data bound to the same view `ViewA`, but I want the `ModelA` in `ListA` use different validation rule.

I think I can achieve it by:

- A: create a new `ModelB` derived from `ModelA` and override the
  Validation functions there; create a new `ListB` of type
  `ObservableCollection<ModelB>` in my `ViewModelB`. 
  But I can't find a way to reuse the `ViewA` with this new list and I need to create a
  new `ViewB` to display it.
- B: use a global flag to indicate the ViewModel, and change the
  validation rule according to that flag. This way I can use the same 
  `ViewA` to link with the same `ListA` in my `ViewModelB`.

But I was really looking for something like:

- create a new `ModelB` derived from `ModelA` and override the
  Validation functions there; somehow redefine my `ListA` to
  `ObservableCollection<ModelB>` in `ViewModelB` and then reuse `ViewA`.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an abstract generic class and derive both ModelA and ModelB from it.

```
public abstract class Model<T> : IDataErrorInfo
  {
    public ObservableCollection<T> Items;

    public virtual string Error
    {
      get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public virtual string this[string columnName]
    {
      get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't get what you mean, and my list at the moment is in the ViewModel.

Comment: @Xtr looks good but if he dervies from ViewModelA in ViewModelB - then probably he adds ModelWithFirstValidiation items in base view model - so it would complicate things (override method to adding items)

Comment: I have no difficulties of modifying my validation rules in the Model, just don't know how to reflect it on to my view (if I want to use the same view)

Answer (score 0):

How about creating some kind of interface

```
interface IModelValidiationService<TModel>
{
    IDataErrorInfo Validate(TModel model);
}
```

or something like that? You would then inject `ValidiationServiceA` into `ViewModelA` and `ValidiationServiceB` into `ViewModelB`.

Comment: Does this means I define my validation rule inside the ViewModel rather than the Model?

Comment: @Bolu it means that you would create two classes (services) responsible for validiating model and you would inject appropiate version to viewmodel. ValidiationRules would lie in another classes - viewmodel should only call Validate method or smth like that.

Comment: It sounds like the exactly the way I would like to do it, but do you have a working example (very simple example will do) ?

Comment: @Bolu i could write some example - i'll do it later ( ~in few hours )